# Loading Image in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, image, writeablebitmap

I want to create a WritableBitmap and display a bitmap from stream onto a Image object. How to do that in Silverlight. I am doing the following which is not working.

```
  Image img = new Image();

  System.IO.Stream stream =  File.OpenRead("1.bmp"); //Getting access permission error

  WriteableBitmap bmp1 = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);
  bmp1.SetSource(stream);
  //do operations with bmp1 

  img.Source = bmp1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight, file I/O is pretty constrained.

Check this post

[In Browser Silverlight Application - Client Side File/Directory access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167198/in-browser-silverlight-application-client-side-file-directory-access)